# Unterminated String Literal without splitting lines

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have researched this issue and I believe that my specific question has not been posed before. I am trying to execute a Javascript entry within a Ruby Selenium Webdriver session. I want to submit a string called **post** into a textbox (labeled "commenttext") on a webpage. Here is the relevant code:

```
commentinput = wait.until {
                    element = driver.find_element(:id, "commenttext")
                    element if element.displayed?
            }

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('commenttext').setAttribute('value', '"+post+"')", commentinput)
```

I am getting an UnterminatedStringLiteral error. I have tried putting < script > and < /script > tags before and after the entry, and I have kept everything on one line. I do not understand the problem. Could you help?

**Edit**

The error that I'm getting in the command line is here:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)
```

The **post** string is from an xml file. I have verified that post is being copied correctly. The issue is not there.

I am using Javascript because Selenium's `fill_in` and `send_keys` methods are inefficient and cause the browser to crash. I am trying to submit a huge block of text, so these methods will not work.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ never concatenate strings with `String#+`, use an interpolation instead: `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('commenttext').setAttribute('value', '#{post}')", commentinput)`. Also, please post the error message you receive.

Comment: What is the value of the `post` variable?

Comment: Hmm, a number of questions come to mind. Usually Selenium is pretty good at waiting for your elements to appear on its own. Why do you have to `wait.until...` explicitly? Once you have waited it should be possible to simply fill in the form element, it should not be necessary to use JavaScript to do this. Why can you not use the `fill_in` command right away?